# Google Analytics XML

Tags: xml, api, google-analytics

I have an issue using the Google Analytics API.  It utilizes JSON but I want to use Cisco Composite to virtualize the data so I have to convert the JSON to XML.  Part of the JSON uses : in naming which when we convert to XML it will not parse.  For example here is the JSON:

{"itemsPerPage":50,"totalResults":19,"totalsForAllResults":{"**ga:pageValue**":"2.52503937007874","ga:entrances":"793","ga:pageviews":"7575","ga:pageviewsPerVisit":"9.55233291298865","ga:uniquePageviews":"3810","ga:avgTimeOnPage":"83.15128280743144","ga:exitRate":"10.46864686468647"},"rows":[["01","0.0","55","579","10.527272727272727","325","65.81870229007633","9.499136442141623"],["02","0.0","5","17","3.4","13","12.166666666666666","29.411764705882355"]}

You will notice the : inside totalsForAllResults (for example **ga:pagevalue**).  I cannot create an XML Schema that will handle this because of the :.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should use an XML namespace as a equivalent here.

Or you could just strip the `ga:`. You'll just need some light automated editing here.